# calling a static method of a class with only an instance

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

If all I have is an instance of an object, can I call a static method of its class?  For fun, let's say I don't know what the name of the class is, only the name of the static method.

Can I do this?  How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the Object's constructor property to get a reference to that object's class object, you can then call the static variable from that class object

```
    package{
        import flash.display.Sprite;

        public class Test extends Sprite{

            public function Test(){
                var variable : A = new A();
                trace((variable as Object).constructor.a());

            }
        }
    }
    class A{
       static function a() : String{
           return "test";
       }
    }
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the constructor property does not work on some Proxy-based classes like XML and XMLList.

Comment: trivally edited to more perfectly answer the question being asked

Answer (score 5):

There is a simpler way, but this assumes that the static functions exists.

```
var myclass:Class = getDefinitionByName("MyClass") as Class;
myclass["myStaticMethod"]();
```

It kinda surprised me that this syntax works.

Comment: It won't pass the compiler.

1180: Call to a possibly undefined method myStaticMethod.

Answer (score 1):

Get the class reference by it's instance.

```
var className:string = getQualifiedClassName(object); //returns the class name    
var classObj:Class = getDefinitionByName(className) as Class; //get a Class object
```

Also see this - [How to get type of variable? and instantiate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137730/how-to-get-type-of-variable-and-instantiate-it)

Comment: Just realized that you probably can't call a static method even with a reference to the Class object. I guess this answer is only halfway there. I don't have access to flex compiler, sorry.

Comment: Yes, you can, check out my answer above.